# Можно ли при каких-то обстоятельствах не ставить в этом предложении запятую?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп

Экран загорелся и на нем высветилось сообщение.

Answer (score 1):

Если не менять само предложение, то без запятой не обойтись.

Answer (score 1):

Запятую можно не ставить, если вместо нее поставить тире, а это вполне возможно, так как обе части сложного предложения обозначают быструю смену событий (со скоростью света).

Answer (score 1):

Можно ли не ставить запятую? Вопрос был именно о том, чтобы **ничего не ставить**, а не **заменять** другим знаком (тире, например).

Действительно, запятая в любом случае обозначает подчеркнутую паузу, а если есть желание прочитать это короткое предложение **в одну фразу, без паузы**. Неужели такое невозможно?

Здесь две предикативные основы, а общего элемента нет (местоимение "на нем" относится только ко второму предложению). Тогда запятая по правилам нужна.

Вероятно,  здесь все дело **"в обстоятельствах"**. В качестве версии, можно обратиться к контексту. Может быть, общий элемент поискать в нем?

Например: *Он торопливо нажал кнопку. **Экран загорелся и на нем высветилось сообщение**.*

Конечно, нежелательно разделять паузой то, что по семантике (по восприятию) является **одним событием.** К тому же дополнение **"на нем"** формально относится ко второму предложению, но по смыслу "объединяет" их.

Другими словами, какие-то обстоятельства для отсутствия запятой надо найти. Но в любом случае это будет **авторская пунктуация**, хотя и обоснованная.